# Wordpress Jquery is not working for custom search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Custom jQuery is not working in wordpress. I am trying to make a custom make wordpress search field where after a button click the input field appear , but this is not working on wordpress. please have a look on my code and please help me to fix what i'm doing wrong.

**[See Demo JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/bwhgytwq/)**

Here is my jQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
            var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
            var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
            var isOpen = false;
            submitIcon.click(function(){
                if(isOpen == false){
                    searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
                    inputBox.focus();
                    isOpen = true;
                } else {
                    searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
                    inputBox.focusout();
                    isOpen = false;
                }
            });  

            submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
                return false;
            });

            searchBox.mouseup(function(){
                return false;
            });

        $(document).mouseup(function(){
            if(isOpen == true){
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                submitIcon.click();
            }
        });
});
function buttonUp(){
    var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
    inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
    if( inputVal !== 0){
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','none');
    } else {
        $('.searchbox-input').val('');
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is nothing wrong with your code , you probably just need to `enqueue` your script properly into Wordpress...

1.) First create **folder** called js.
Your Theme File structure should look like so:

-index.php

-single.php

-js <-- This is your folder containing *custom-search-field.js*

-other files.php

2.) Create the file called *custom-search-field.js* and copy the code you posted to this file. Than add that file to your ***js folder***.

3.) Add code below to your **functions.php** file

```
/**
* Enqueues scripts and styles.
*
*/
function enqueue_js_scripts_and_css() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );//Enqueues Jquery that comes with Wordpress
    /*
    * Registers a script file in WordPress to be linked to a page 
    * later using the wp_enqueue_script()
    * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
    * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts
    */

    wp_register_script( 'custom_search_field', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-search-field.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false );

   // Enqueue your custom search field JS file.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_search_field' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_js_scripts_and_css' );
```

Comment: Thanks I made mistake I added it on theme js